# Are CIN/COUT in series or parallel in this TranSim EE-Sim output?

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator

I'm needing to use this MAX20034 voltage regulator. Because I know very little about voltage regulators (in how they are structured), I went to MAXIM-Integrated's website and was able to find a simulator using TranSim EE-Sim. It is exactly what I'm looking for, I just need help figuring out this last part.If you notice on the far right side where Cout1 / CIN / Cou2 (from top to bottom) are, you notice at the bottom, below the resistance is either a 2x or 3x. **I have no idea if this is saying place 2/3 capacitors in series or in parallel**. The only thing that I do know is that in the bill of materials, it does have the multiples of capacitors, so I'm not just going insane here. Any ideas?

[image: MAX20034 schematic]

Here are some specs for reference if it helps at all. I didn't make most of them, but it's in the report outputted from EE-Sim:

- nominal input voltage: 9V
- input voltage ripple: 0.5%
- output config: fixed output voltage
- output 1 voltage: 5V
- output 2 voltage: 3.3V
- output 1 current: 5A
- output 2 current: 2A
- output 1 voltage ripple: 0.1%
- output 2 voltage ripple: 0.1%
- load 1 step current: 2.5A
- load 2 step current: 1A
- load 1 start current: 5A
- load 2 start current: 2A
- load 1 step edge rate: 1A/us
- load 2 step edge rate: 1A/us
- output 1 voltage load step over/undershoot: 5%
- output 2 voltage load step over/undershoot: 5%
- mode: PWM
- switching frequency: 600KHz
- inductor 1 current ratio (LIR1): 0.3
- inductor 2 current ratio (LIR2): 0.3

I sent a case to MAXIM-Integrated to see what they say, but if anyone knows so I can update sooner, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Place these caps in parallel.

Comment: @BrianDrummond can I ask how you know this or can you give some reference as to how you came to this conclusion?

Comment: General principle that you want to reduce high frequency impedance to ground. Notice they spec the ESR of these capacitors too.

Comment: @BrianDrummond that makes more sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the purpose of "Cout" is to stabilize the output voltage
They serve as a tank which charges during the switch's ON time, and which discharges during the OFF time.

Placing them in parallel allows for a larger tank and thus a smoother output voltage

Be careful not to exceed the recommended value otherwise the capacitors may not have time to charge during the ON time.

The other purpose of "Cout" is to filter out high frequency noise,
for this, taking capacitors with a low ESR is recommended (placing the capacitors in parallel also allows to reduce the ESR)